# The best way to copy OS on RAID10 and lvm partition

Tags: linux, backup, rhel6, dd, clonezilla

I need to backup/clone the entire operating system.
The problem is it's 2TB of data on lvm partition and RAID10 (i do not know is it dedicated controller or fake RAID in BIOS. Probably the second option)
Which tool will be the best for this ? 
Ghost does not support the lvm partition
dd is dangerous because it is easy to destroy the data. (backup will be creating by other technician)

i need help. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get `knoppix` and use `dd_rescue` to copy the LVM to another LVM, physical or network location.

Example:

```
**to local drive** 
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/media/sda5 bs=512 count=1

**to network location**
dd_rescue /dev/sda1 – | ssh root@somehost ” cat – > /some/path/filename.img
```

**UPDATE:**

To copy the data to another HD, first, you need to know which drive you're copying from and which drive you're copying to.  So, you'll use `lshw` or `fdisk -l` or `disklabel`.  Whichever application will let you list out all your disks and volumes.

For example, if you want to copy `/dev/sda1` (partition 1 on disk 1) to `/dev/sdb1` (partition 1 on disk 2), you can do:

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1
```

The `bs` is the byte size you want to use.  Generally, larger byte sizes allow for faster copying.

Apparently, I've been out of the game for a while, and now `gddrescue` is available, which is supposed to be more powerful.  It follows the same principles:

```
 ddrescue -f -n /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 logfile
```

Where `/dev/sda1` is the partition of the LVM and `/dev/sdb1` is the partition on the new drive you want, and `logfile` is the location/name of the logfile you'll want to generate.  `-f` forces even on error and `-n` skips areas that are damaged or hard to copy.  You can add `-b` to change the bytesize, but the default is `512`, which is sufficient for most use cases.  You can use a higher number if you want to go faster, like, `4096`.

Comment: I forgot to write an important thing. It must be cloned to one hdd. so as i understand the command dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/media/sda5 bs=512 count=1 will be changed to dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/media/sda5/<image_name.img> bs=512 count=1 ?

Comment: See my updated answer